# How do I use a value from appsettings.json in my startup.cs ? - Not instantiate but actually use the value

Tags: c#, .net, appsettings

If the following is my ConfigureServices in startup.cs, how do I get the value "http://example.com" from my appsettings? I do not want the string "http://example.com" to be explicitly mentioned in my startup.cs - rather I want to use IOptions and then get the value there.

This is what my appsettings currently looks like

```
  "CORSOriginHosts": {
    "AllowedHosts": "http://136.243.73.96:1337"
  },
```

I have already created an Options class called CORSOriginHosts

This is what my startup currently looks like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CORSOriginHosts>(Configuration.GetSection("CORSOriginHosts"));
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com");
                              });
        });
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

This is what I want it to look like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CORSOriginHosts>(Configuration.GetSection("CORSOriginHosts"));
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  //NO STRINGS PRESENT HERE - this is sample code
                                  builder.WithOrigins(CORSOriginHosts.Value.AllowedHost);
                              });
        });
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you can´t just use Configuration.GetSection("CORSOriginHosts") instead of building an IOptions just to pass the value in this point? It seens to me you´re not gonna use this
CORSOriginHosts class anywhere else, so why bother creating it?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
               builder =>
               {                                                            
                    builder.WithOrigins(Configuration.GetSection("CORSOriginHosts"));
               });
        });
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```